# Enlarge Certain Parts of an SVG

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am trying to make rocket having a fire at the base, so that it looks like that fire is burning.

What I am trying to do is enlarging the height of the fire and then decreasing it again so that I look like it's burning.

I am having SVG image and using keyframes to do it.

```
.fire{
  animation: fire_effect 1s infinite;
}          
@keyframes fire_effect 
{
  0%   {transform: scale(1,1);}
  100% {transform:scale(1,1.5);}
}
```

But it's not getting enlarged, infact it's going downwards. Kindly help me out on how can I increase the height of the fire.
I have a code-pen, here 
http://codepen.io/eugeneprateek/pen/WwqVaE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `transform-origin: top;` in this case.

I tried inside of your pen and it works properly as you want.

Comment: It's not working in FireFox, it's only working in Chrome I tried adding -webkit and -moz

Comment: @Eugene it works by [specification](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), but with svg elements, unfortunately, it's [a known bug for Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061)

I think, it can be fixed only with JS

Comment: you can eventually add both transform-origin for FF and prefixed for webkit/opera : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MyNgwP I.E. doesn't do anything so no worries about it i guess

Comment: well it works in My firefox , else i would not bother to post anything :) (W7 FF 44.01) test the codepen, feed me back ;)

Comment: Tested in my FF 48, and it doesn't work, maybe they've changed transform-box in newer versions, but the bug in the link above is confirmed and still not resolved :(

Comment: okay, i understood they would not change anything untill candidate version. ... never mind then ...

Comment: @vicodin There's no bug in FF 48. The bug is either in Chrome or the specification depending on your point of view. In other words if Firefox implements the w3c specification but Chrome does not, who's got a bug?

Comment: Ok, maybe it's not bug, but expected behavior is in webkit browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a style effect on a "g" tag, try to move the class assignment on the two "polygon" tags inside the "g" tag

Comment: I already have a class named fire. Can you show me an small demo/example ?

Comment: Thanks for updating your comment, I am trying your suggestion.

Comment: i changed a little your effect in css now it works:
http://codepen.io/and_valentini/pen/VaoZwv?editors=1100

Comment: @AndreaValentini it looks ugly and doesn't stretch vertically